# Is there a simple script to "duplicate/clone" a SQL Server database on the same server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm looking for a way to automatize a copy of a database each day on the same SQL Server.

For example, I have a database `MyDB`. I would like, each day, do a copy of `MyDB` in a `MyDB_TEST` on the same server.

Is there any simple script to do this "simple" task ?

I found this script:

```
backup database OriginalDB
to disk = 'D:\backup\OriginalDB_full.bak'
with init, stats =10;

restore database new_db_name
from disk = 'D:\backup\OriginalDB_full.bak'
with stats =10, recovery,
move 'logical_Data_file' to 'D:\data\new_db_name.mdf',
move 'logical_log_file' to 'L:\log\new_db_name_log.ldf'
```

But I don't understand for what to replace in 'logical_Data_file' and 'logical_log_file'.

It's a move and I want a copy of my database...Why these two latest lines are "move" ?

I think I misunderstand this script...anyone could help me please?

EDIT :

I just edited my code like this :

```
backup database MY_DB
to disk = 'D:\BACKUP\MY_DB.bak'
with init, stats =10;

restore database MY_DB_NEW
from disk = 'D:\BACKUP\MY_DB.bak'
with stats =10, recovery,
move 'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLDIVALTO\MSSQL\DATA\MY_DB.mdf' to 'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLDIVALTO\MSSQL\DATA\MY_DB_new.mdf',
move 'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLDIVALTO\MSSQL\DATA\MY_DB_log.mdf' to 'D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLDIVALTO\MSSQL\DATA\MY_DB_new_log.ldf'
```

And I sadly get an error telling the logical file "MY_DB.mdf" is not a part of the My_DB_New database...use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to get logicals file name.

I don't understand where is my mistake in this script, any inputs?

Comment: "Move" here just means "use this other location/name I specify for the files, not the location/names stored in the backup", and that's necessary because the original location is already occupied by the original database. The files are not actually getting moved, just restored somewhere else.

Comment: You're using *physical* file names. The error talks about *logical* file names for a reason, and even helpfully tells you what statement to use to discover those file names.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, it was that ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you `RESTORE` a database, unless you specify otherwise it would create the same files that it had in the previously; same name, same path. As you want a copy, that would be **overwriting** the existing ones. That would, obviously fail, as those files are in use by your original database.

Therefore you need tell the instance to put the database files ("move" them) to a different path, hence the `MOVE` clause. This means that you then don't have the 2 databases conflicting over trying to use or write other each others files.

---

*Side note, this type of thing does normally, however, tend to suggest an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info), though that is a different question.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, i edited my code ( and editing my question) but saddly i got an error message aout my logical file name :(

Comment: I wrote it in the original post but i just find it....logical files names doesn't have a path !

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTION:

I wasn't putting the logical file name but the file name instead.
Just put the logical file name without the path!

Comment: Is this an answer? Or additional information for the question?